# How to convert result from sql stored procedure into a list

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, edmx

I am trying to learn EF, C# and MVC at the same time so I apologise if this is a bit basic.

I am trying to get a result set from a SQL Server stored procedure into a model.

I have created a EDMX file and have stored procedure imported and a result set exists in a cs file - see below.

```
public partial class prBGGetYourTasks_Result
{
    public int CompanyTaskID { get; set; }
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string TimeLeft { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I have then created a class in models folder with the exact definition called Task.

I am trying to populate the model with results of the SP with this code:

```
public class TaskList : List<Task> {
    public TaskList GetTasks()
        {
            BGEntities BGDB = new BGEntities();
            TaskList task_list = new TaskList();
            task_list = BGDB.prBGGetYourTasks(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ToList();
            return task_list;
    }
}
```

However it is coming up "cannot implicitly convert type 'Genric.List to 'Task.TaskList'. I have tried trying to a variable of the result type and also casting into result set type.

Please advise if I am also going about it the wrong way.

I have previously used a sql reader and loop to populate the model but I figure there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
TaskList task_list = new TaskList();
task_list = BGDB.prBGGetYourTasks(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ToList
```

You're trying to assign a `List<Task>` to a `TaskList`.  Inheritence does not work this way.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
TaskList taskList = new TaskList();

//This will compile
tasks = taskList;

//This will not
taskList = tasks;
```

You may want to get rid of `TaskList` altogether and just use `List<Task>`, it doesn't seem like you're adding any a new members of behavior to it.

Comment: In addition to answer: if you wan add your function to predefined class(`GetTasks`) then use ["Extension"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your Function Import within the Data Model is set to return a collection of ComplexTypes not your Entity type as you are wanting.

To fix.  Double click your function(stored procedure) in Data Model-> Function Imports.  Within the dialog box, you will find a section entitled "Returns a collection of".  Select your entity type from the dropdown Entities:.  Click OK.   This one frustrated me for a while too.

Hopefully this helps someone looking for an answer.  Really hope the original post has found a work around that works for them!